# C# Replacing Multiple Spaces with 1 space leaving special characters intact

Tags: c#, regex

Having a bit of a problem as I have to translate a string into a table. I'd like to remove multiple spaces, but not all of them. So the data in text comes back with lots of spaces in between like so:

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE\r\n 
 services                                    0  Disc                      \r\n 
 console                                     1  Conn                      \r\n 
                   alinav                    2  Disc                      \r\n  
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen                    \r\n
```

I would like to still keep the \r\n\ values that will define my rows, and I want to keep the empty value which would be legit under the columns, and I want to keep the spaces to define the columns. But I want to remove the extra spaces that I don't want to be fed into the values.

I've tried:

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\s{2,}", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);

output = output.Replace("  ", " ");
```

But the first one just removes everything (things I need and don't need). And the second one still leaves too many spaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the data is delimited by position, not by characters; is that correct? If so, you should extract by position; something like:

```
foreach (string s in output.Split())
{
    var sessionName = s.Substring(0, 18).Trim();
    var userName = s.Substring(18, 19).Trim();
    var id = Int32.Parse(s.Substring(37, 8).Trim());
    var whateverType = s.Substring(45, 12).Trim();
    var device = s.Substring(57, 6).Trim();
}
```

Of course you need to do proper error checking, and should probably put the field widths in an array and calculate positions instead of hard-coding them as I have shown.

Comment: Also, another option which may be a little bit naffed but might work OK, is to remove the spaces as per the first proposed regex. Then double the space in between the values. Then Find numeric value and remove all spaces before the first letter, so the extra space isn't fed to the values :) Only I don't know Regex, so I don't know how a query to remove spaces between number and a letter would look like

Comment: I think trying to cut out the values by their position sounds too complicated, as I wouldn't know the accurate width of the columns. I can't tell for sure where one ends and one starts by looking at the string coming in

Comment: Alina, you do not have to know the widths of the columns; just the position of the first character, you can calculate the widths from that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do two things:

Use **space explicitly** in the regular expression, `\s` includes weird characters like (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`,...) as well, thus:

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, @" +", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Or apply the second method **until convergence**:

```
string s2 = output;
do {
    output = s2;
    s2 = s2.Replace("  "," ");
} while(output != s2);
```

In most cases the **first method will outperform the second one**. This because the first method groups all substrings with two or more spaces. Regexes are in general a bit slower than simple string replacement, but if the string contains sequences with many spaces, the first method will be faster.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried both solutions. But the issue is trickier. With both the solutions they work in the way that one space is left between all the data. So for the first row, for example, I only get back "services", "0", "Disc". But what I want to see coming back is "services", "", "0", "Disc", "" , "" - to match the number of columns that I have. So things to achieve are: 1) Remove unnecessary spaces 2) Split by spaces 3) Still have some spaces as values to match columns. So making 1 and 3 work is the tricky part I can't get passed. Thanks

Comment: Also it's unfortunate that I can't control the format of the data I receive, so I can't use a different delimiter for spaces that would define individual cell (split) and space that would represent a value

Comment: @AlinaVinnichek: Do you want to split the data based on the pattern? You can't do this with a regex. I propose you open a new question that is more specific to your problem...

Comment: Hi I can split it without any problems. The problem is removing the excessive spaces, but leaving the spaces to have as values under the columns within the rows.

Comment: Why do you want empty strings interspersed in the resulting collection? And if there is indeed a legitimate reason for having these, why can't you just insert them yourself after using either of these approaches?

Comment: Because I want a table, so if User Name doesn't have a value underneath it, I want it to have an empty value. Otherwise, I am only ending up with 3 values to fill 6 columns - which will not give me a correct information

Comment: Plus programmatically how would it know under which columns it needs to insert the spaces? Because the example I've shown will not always be exactly the same.